# How to use devtoolset in autotools

Tags: linux, gnu-make, autotools, devtoolset

I want to enable devtoolset-9 from autotools i.e. from configure.ac. I need to do this as I am using gcc 4 and gcc 9 both for the compilation. I know the option *scl enable devtoolset-9 'make'* but want a mechanism to enable it from configure script.

I tried multiple options like setting up SHELL, CC variable as *CC='source scl_source enable devtoolset-9; gcc'* but none of them worked.

Please let me know can it be done?

Comment: Are you asking how to write / update `configure.ac` to do ... something ..., or are you asking how to express to an already-built Autotools `configure` script which GCC to use?

Comment: And what makes you think you need to use different C compilers together to build one project?  That sounds both unwise and unnecessary to me.